# Gerrit its-jira plugin doest find projest specyfic actions file

Tags: plugins, jira, gerrit

Acording to documentation (https://community.wandisco.com/s/article/Guide-to-ITS-Jira-plugin-with-Gerrit#project-specific-rules):
"This is achieved by adding a actions-its-jira.config file to the refs/meta/config branch of the project"

Plugin should looking for actions config file in /refs/meta/config, if doesnt find, should use general actions config file form gerrit/etc dir.

I've added actions file actions-its-jira.config to gerrit project under refs/meta/config branch, and I've removed this file from gerrit etc. After restart gerrit i have following error:

com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.its.base.workflow.RuleBase : Neither global rule file /home/gerrit/gerrit-2-15-3_20181006_091326/etc/its/actions.config nor Its specific rule file/home/gerrit/gerrit-2-15-3_20181006_091326
/etc/its/actions-its-jira.config exist. Please configure rules.